# Duda pySerial con métodos write y read

Tags: python, arduino, tkinter, pyserial

una duda con respecto a enviar y recibir múltiples datos utilizando la librería pySerial de Python, según lo que entiendo, la comunicación por puerto serial funciona con variables de tipo byte. 
 ¿Como hago para enviar con `write`cuatro variables diferentes y luego con `read` recibir dos variables diferentes? 
Como ejemplo:

```
    import serial
    import time

    envioSerial = serial.Serial("COM4", 9600) 
    lecturaSerial = serial.Serial("COM4", 9600) 
    time.sleep(2) 
    envioSerial.write("variable1" + "variable2" + "variable3" + "variable4")
    while True:
        lecturaSerial.read("variable5" + "variable6")
```

¿Qué debo hacer para enviar las cuatro variables con `write` diferenciadas por algún carácter y después separarlas para el respectivo uso de cada variable? (aplicando lo mismo para las dos variables recibidas con `read`) Además, ¿Qué puedo hacer para enviar las variables como `float` y no generar conflicto con la lectura en `byte`?